# flutter web: redirect on logout without context using Hive, ChangeNotifier and go_router

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I am using Hive and go_router in my flutter web app and am trying to implement auth redirect logic on logout. Here is the relevant code:

Top widget of the app, MyApp:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _hiveDB = HiveService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ChangeNotifierProvider<HiveService>.value(
        value: _hiveDB,
        child: MaterialApp.router(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Portal',
          routerConfig: MyAppRouter(_hiveDB).router,
        ),
      );
)
```

The router with two routes and redirect logic:

```
class MyAppRouter {
  final HiveService _hiveDB;

  MyAppRouter(this._hiveDB);

  GoRouter get router {
    return GoRouter(
      initialLocation: '/auth',
      redirect: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        final bool loggedIn = _hiveDB.loggedIn;
        final bool loggingIn = state.matchedLocation == '/auth';
        if (!loggedIn) {
          return '/auth';
        }

        if (loggingIn) {
          return '/events';
        }
        return null;
      },
      refreshListenable: _hiveDB,
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: '/auth',
          pageBuilder: (context, GoRouterState state) {
            return NoTransitionPage(
              key: state.pageKey,
              name: state.name,
              child: const Text('auth page'),
            );
          },
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/events',
          pageBuilder: (context, GoRouterState state) {
            return NoTransitionPage(
              key: state.pageKey,
              name: state.name,
              child: const Text('events page')
            );
          },
        ),
        // other routes
      ],
    )
  }
}
```

Finally, hive service which notifies the listeners on login / logout:

```
class HiveService extends ChangeNotifier {
  HiveService();

  bool get loggedIn => accessToken != null && accessToken!.isNotEmpty;

  void login(String accessToken) {
    this.accessToken = accessToken;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void logout() {
    this.accessToken = null;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  String? get accessToken {
    return Hive.box<dynamic>('userSettings').get('accessToken');
  }

  set accessToken(String? token) {
    Hive.box<dynamic>('userSettings').put('accessToken', token);
  }
}
```

When I need to log user out manually, I use `context.read<HiveService>().logout();` and everything works as expected.

I also want to log user out on 401 response from server, for which I am calling `HiveService().logout()` in a function without access to context – which does change the accessToken, but does not notify listeners – it redirects only after the user refreshes the page. Please, tell me what am I missing?